# mysql database stops responding on cloud ec2 in some time

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have installed moodle it works fine for some time. but in some sort of time mysql throws error "Database overloaded !"(Its a moodle message). restarting mysql service again starts working. but again in some time same thing happens.

I have tried giving the remote access to mysql via configuring security groups. inbound is set to 0.0.0.0 for mysql conf. There are no issues on localhost.

I don't conclude whats wrong !

Please help !

Comment: Thats not a firewall issue. Check the mysql error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

Adding the swap page solved !

here is the link you need to go for :- http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/05/amazon-ec2-linux-micro-swap-space.html